# Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp 34.201.236.93:443: connect: connection refused

Tags: docker

I'm getting the error in the title when running `docker run hello-world`. The host is an Ubuntu Server 18.04 sitting behind a corporate firewall. I tried configuring the proxy settings in every which way I could find:

- [`systemd`](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/)
- [`/etc/default/docker`](https://movidius.github.io/ncsdk/docker_proxy.html)

Needles to say that none of them worked. Some relevant outputs:

```
axcel@axcel:~$ systemctl show --property=Environment docker
Environment=
axcel@axcel:~$ docker run hello-world
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: 
dial tcp 52.206.40.44:443: connect: connection refused.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Settings for the host itself are obviously working since I was able to download and install docker. I have absolutely no idea why docker isn't taking the proxy settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it was caused by an unescaped backslash in the `http-proxy.conf` file.

```
[Service]
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://domain\user:passwordproxy.example.com:443/"
```

Should be

```
[Service]
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://domain\\user:passwordproxy.example.com:443/"
```